# CSS transition triggered by responsive breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-transitions

**The background:**

I have a Bootstrap nav bar that is supposed to slide out from the right as opposed to drop down from the top. I didn't want to use complicated off-canvas or other plug-ins for this. It seems to work just fine by pushing the left coordinate of the containing div off to the right (100%) when it is not visible. I don't get the horizontal scroll bar on the actual page and did not investigate if it is because of Codepen or a missing CSS rule, so please ignore that.

**The problem:**

The CSS transition gets triggered by either a click (via class change) or (unwanted) by a media query/responsive breakpoint (by resizing the browser width from +1200 down until you hit the breakpoint). Then the CSS transition starts because the left coordinate of the DIV is 0 for the desktop and needs to change to 100% for the tablet resolution, thus making the menu invisible. This should not be animated.

I need to somehow prevent the breakpoint from triggering the transition. I know there are JavaScript options, but I am hoping for a logical fix in my CSS that I am not seeing.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sKLvn

```css
/* nav bar */
.navbar-tablet {
    display: none; }
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    clear: both; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold; }

.navbar-stuff, 
.navbar-links {
    float: left; }

.navbar-stuff {    
    clear: both; 
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin-top: 20px; }
    .navbar-stuff .navbar-callbutton {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase; }
    .navbar-stuff .navbar-address {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #838181;  
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px; }
    .form-icon .fa-circle,
    .email-icon .fa-circle {
        color: #0f9cd8; }
    .facebook-icon .fa-circle {
        color: #537bbd;  }
    .linkedin-icon .fa-circle {
        color: #2085c7;  }
    .twitter-icon .fa-circle {
        color: #78cdf0;  }



.navbar > div {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    border-color: #2b2b2b; }
#navbar-collapse {
    display: block;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    border-color: #2b2b2b;
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
 -moz-transition: left 1s ease, width 0s ease-out 1s, border-width 0s ease-out 1s;
 -webkit-transition: left 1s ease, width 0s ease-out 1s, border-width 0s ease-out 1s;
 -ms-transition: left 1s ease, width 0s ease-out 1s, border-width 0s ease-out 1s; 
 transition: left 1s ease, width 0s ease-out 1s, border-width 0s ease-out 1s; }
    #navbar-collapse.showing {
     left: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     -moz-transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s, border-width 0s ease-out 0.1s;
     -webkit-transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s, border-width 0s ease-out 0.1s;
     -ms-transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s, border-width 0s ease-out 0.1s;
     transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s, border-width 0s ease-out 0.1s; }


@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .navbar-tablet {
        display: inline-block;
        clear: none; 
        text-transform: uppercase;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold; }
        .navbar-tablet,
        .navbar-tablet:focus {
            color: white; }
        .navbar-tablet .dimwit,
        .navbar-tablet:focus .dimwit {
            color: #999; }
        .navbar-tablet:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #98e0ff; } 

    .navbar-tablet.collapsed {
        display: none; }
}


@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 0px; }

    .jumbotron {
        max-height: 125px;
        min-height: 125px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2; }

    .navbar {
        border: none;
        padding: 20px; }

    #navbar-collapse {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 100px;
        left: 0px; 
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent; 
        -moz-transition: none;
        -webkit-transition: none;
        -ms-transition: none;
        transition: none; }
  
  
  
      .navbar > div {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent; }

    .navbar-tablet {
        display: none; }

    .navbar-links {
        text-align: justify;
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: 80%; }

    .navbar-stuff {
        display: none; }

    .navbar-inverse {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent; }

        .navbar-inverse.scrolling {
            border-color: #2b2b2b;
            background: rgb(75,75,75); 
            background: rgba(75,75,75, 0.9); }

        .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
            margin-left: 10px;
            text-align: right;
            padding-top: 32px;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 20px;
            height: 70px;
            clear: none;
            font-size: 1.1em; }

        .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
            margin-left: 5%; }
            .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,
            .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
                color: #2b2b2b; }
                .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand .dimwit,
                .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus .dimwit {
                    color: #2b2b2b;}
            .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand.current,
            .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand.current:focus {
                color: #009ddc; }
                .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand.current .dimwit,
                .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus.current .dimwit {
                    color: #009ddc;}
        .navbar-inverse.scrolling .navbar-brand,
        .navbar-inverse.scrolling .navbar-brand:focus {
            color: white; }
        .navbar-inverse.scrolling  .navbar-brand .dimwit,
        .navbar-inverse.scrolling  .navbar-brand:focus .dimwit {
            color: white; }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover {
        color: #98e0ff !important; } 

    .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,
    .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: white; }
        .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand .dimwit,
        .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus .dimwit {
            color: white; }
            .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand.current,
            .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand.current:focus {
                color: #000; }
                .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand.current .dimwit,
                .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus.current .dimwit {
                    color: #000;}
            .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse.scrolling .navbar-brand.current,
            .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse.scrolling .navbar-brand.current:focus {
                color: #009ddc; }
                .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse.scrolling .navbar-brand.current .dimwit,
                .hasJumboTron .navbar-inverse.scrolling .navbar-brand:focus.current .dimwit {
                    color: #009ddc;}
    
    #logoplaceholder {
        background-image: url('../images/logo_blue_md.png');
        width: 77px;
        height: 69px; }

    .hasJumboTron #logoplaceholder {
        background-image: url('../images/logo_white.png');
        width: 74px;
        height: 68px; }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://development.podconsulting.net:8088/js/pod.js"></script>
<script src="http://development.podconsulting.net:8088/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="/"><div id="logoplaceholder"></div></a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                        <div class="icon-bar"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar-collapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="navbar-links">
                        <!-- Menu -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Services <span class="dimwit">+</span> Philosophy</a>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Case Studies</a>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">People <span class="dimwit">+</span> Culture</a>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jobs&nbsp;<div class="jobnumber"><p>2</p></div></a>
                        <!-- End Menu -->
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you not just remove the transition in the appropriate media query?

Comment: No, because the appropriate media query is the default (mobile first) and the transition is needed there. Remember, once you have hit the breakpoint coming from above 1200, you are in mobile territory.

Comment: Have you tried tying the transition CSS to the class that gets added when you click it? By default, have no transition, so it will behave properly when resizing the browser, but when the user clicks the button, add the class (and thus the transition css).

Comment: tomaroo, I think I know what you mean and that would be a logical way out, but how do I tie a transition to a class and not the property that is changing? There are really two transitions, one for sliding in and one for sliding out. One of the transition rules is always active - unless I use a JavaScript timer to remove the class and/or transition once it has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so I'm going to have to leave my comment / answer here.

Why not just leave it and split it up into separate css files, then when you detect mobile (or desktop) deploy the appropriate css file?

If you use transitions on your element, it will transition if a media query is triggered, there's not much you can do about it whilst using basic css, you'd need to implement a javascript / jQuery hack.

Comment: fyi I did not down-vote you. I am starting to realize this, too. I think the solution is using separate classes for the transitions in the in/out state (i.e. not the default for either case), add the class when the menu button is clicked, and remove it with a jQuery timer once completed. Ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use:

```
left: -100%;
```

instead of:

```
  transform: translateX(-100%);
```

then

```
transition: all .4s;
```

Please feel free to alter to your case but it has helped me with a NO BOOTSTRAP project.

Comment: This solved my problem, but I don't understand why it did.  I was using translateX instead of left.